# How to navigate from a fragment to another popping the current one from the stack?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I have the following navigation graph

```
         ->  Frag B
        /
Frag A  -->  Frag C
        \
         ->  Frag D



# Frag A is the startDestination
```

My current stack is [Frag A]. Knowing that the current destination is Frag A and that one wants to navigate from Frag A to Frag B clearing Frag A from the stack, how can one do it?

I tried:

- 1: setting up an action with `popUpTo="Frag A"`, `popUpToInclusive="true"` and `destination="Frag B"`
- 2: calling `findNavController().popBackStack()` before navigating

but none of those ways worked. For the first case the fragment remains in the stack and for the second the app misbehaves and the navigation doesn't happen.

---

Current stack: [Frag A]

Intent: navigate to Frag B clearing [Frag A] from the stack

resulting stack: [Frag B]

Comment: Can you do this, enter the flag A in the session and check that the last session is active, pop up it, I think

Comment: The only reason `popUpTo` wouldn't work would be if the destination you specify in `popUpTo` isn't actually on the back stack. In that case, you'd get a `NavController` log message in logcat saying "Ignoring popBackStack to destination R.id.fragment_a as it was not found on the current back stack". Do you get that INFO level log message in your logcat?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've just checked it, that log is not being printed. One thing that I found out in the meantime is that if I use `popBackStack` instead of `navigateUp()` everything works as expected (when using the action from "1" and navigating back from Frag B). `navigateUp()` seems to do some additional stuff that adds back a new Frag A (the startDestination of the graph) to the stack when it is about to get empty.